# Map is flickering once displayed on page

Tags: angularjs, angular-google-maps

I have the following code. When the map is loaded it just starts flickering. I've tried both ways of loading Google Maps API v3 but I can't figure out why it won't work. Does anyone have any suggestions?

[Video of the flickering map](http://streamable.com/evxw)

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/lzMa1I50SBDS3dQGOYGv)

```
<div ng-repeat="data in dataArray">
    <div ng-click="data.showMap = !data.showMap">
        <div>View Map</div>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="data.showMap" class="item" style="height:300px;">
        <ui-gmap-google-map center='data.map_data.center' zoom='data.map_data.zoom'></ui-gmap-google-map>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think its happening because angular is watching for changes in your `data.showMap` variable.

Comment: how do I stop watching for changes? @ODelibalta